# Replace , (comma) within brackets in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to Replace all instances of `,` (comma) in a string like:

```
word, synonym, synonym (definition 1, definition2)
```

I do not want to touch anything that is before first `(` and I do not want to alter any text within brackets - all I need is to replace all instances of comma with semicolon INSIDE of the brackets so I get something like:

```
word, synonym, synonym (definition 1; definition2)
```

I tried with `\(.*[\, ].*\)` to capture all that is in the brackets, but I do not know how to set Notepad++ to replace just the comma and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to replace , within brackets to a semicolon?

Try this:

```
Find: \((.*)(,)(.*)\)
Explanation: \(     - Literally capture a left bracket
             (.*)   - Captures everything and groups it until...
             (,)    - Captures the comma and groups it
             (.*)   - Captures everything and groups it until...
             \)     - ... the literal right bracket.

Replace With: \($1;$3\)
Explanation:  We replace everything caught above, meaning we need to put in...
              \(    - The literal left bracket again
              $1    - The first group we captured before (everything before ,)
              ;     - Our replacement for the comma, a semi colon
              $3    - The third group we captured before (we skipped 2, the comma, and got everything after)
              \)    - Finally, our literal right bracket again
```

I could have made it slightly more accurate and instead done:

```
Find: \((.*)(?:,)(.*)\)
Explanation: (?:) means the group doesn't capture, so we now replace with:
Replace With: \($1;$2\)
```

In REGEX mode, of course.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, it worked:)

Comment: Could you explain the syntax to me (if you find some spare time)? I am regex wannabe but it's still a long way to go:(

Comment: Edited my comment with explanations - if you could mark as the answer and upvote if it worked and helped you :)